# Faster select when filtering with second or third sorted column

Tags: clickhouse

We have a time series table with the following definition

```sql
CREATE TABLE timeseries.mytable
(
    `ts` DateTime('UTC'),
    `src_ip` String,
    `dst_ip` String,
    `col_other` String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toDate(tr)
ORDER BY (dst_ip,ts,src_ip)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192

SELECT count(*) FROM timeseries.mytable;
# Elapsed 0.004 sec. Has 383M records


SELECT count(*) FROM timeseries.timeseries WHERE dst_ip = 'a.b.c.d';
# Elapsed: 0.085 sec.

SELECT count(*) FROM timeseries.timeseries WHERE src_ip = 'a.b.c.d';
# Elapsed: 53.031 sec
```

As can be seen above, filtering the data using the first sorted column (dst_ip) is very quick.

How can I make the select using the third sorted column (src_ip) faster?

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- the third query (*WHERE src_ip = 'a.b.c.d'*) works slowly because of *index is not used* and CH uses full scan. No good way to make it faster besides as redesign the primary key or if this query calculates just aggregates use the additional [AggregatingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/aggregatingmergetree/)-table
- use-cases which you provided looks as artificial because the calculation of row count by *all* dataset is not key use-case for timeseries data. Why the result not restricted by *dst_ip* and *ts*?
- consider using [ClickHouse AggregatingMergeTree Approach](https://www.altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-continues-to-crush-time-series) when need to calculate aggregated-values (as *count* in your case)
- design of primary key required the understanding as CH use it in query optimization (see [Primary Keys and Indexes in Queries](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#primary-keys-and-indexes-in-queries), [More secrets of ClickHouse Query Performance](https://youtu.be/1TGGCIr6dMY?t=466))
- it recommends using the [monotonic index](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#use-of-index-for-partially-monotonic-primary-keys)
- to choose the best index need to make the series of tests to find the index fittest for concrete use-cases

---

I would suggest the next primary keys:

```sql
/* [pretty suspicious suggestion] Remove date-column (it makes much slower the all date range queries with a range less than Daily). */
ORDER BY (dst_ip, src_ip)

/* Define the granularity of date. Instead of toStartOfHour can be used any interval less than 'Daily' (where Daily is defined by partition key) */
ORDER BY (dst_ip, toStartOfHour(ts), src_ip)

/* Move the date to the first position (it makes faster queries with date range without dst_ip and get monotonic-index related advantages). */
ORDER BY (toStartOfHour(ts), dst_ip, src_ip)
```

For each primary key need to choose the more effective *Index granularity*-value.

Comment: The only way is to duplicate data to the second table with another `ORDER BY` and query that new table.

Comment: Thanks @vladimir. The use case is to just extract the data using src_ip or dst_ip for a given time interval.  Aggregations are done by downstream data pipelines. I will try the  combination of primary keys suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As for 2022, the solution is to use Data Skipping Index https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#table_engine-mergetree-data_skipping-indexes for src_ip

Answer (score 0):

You should try testing by keeping different order in ORDER BY clause depending upon value cardinality of your columns. In this case, maybe trying bringing src_ip before ts in ORDER by class.

In MergeTree engine, rows are sorted on the basis of ORDER BY keys in each partition.

After that, you can decide the final arrangement of columns in ORDER by clause depending upon how your application will query data most of the items.

You can find a similar discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clickhouse/U-NK-VsBelg).